# Select Drop Down from Web Page with IE object

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

Have the below code for a drop down selection in VBA .

When I run this I get the error on the bold line saying "Runtime error 91 - Object variable or with block variable not set " ..New to VBA ....

```
Sub NACDP()
' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "https://cdeployna.cognizant.com/"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

' Input the userid and password
    ie.Document.getElementById("loginControl_UserName").Value = ""
    ie.Document.getElementById("loginControl_Password").Value = ""

' Click the "Login" button
    ie.Document.getElementById("loginControl_LoginButton").Click

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ddlRoles").selectedindex = 1
    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ddlRoles").FireEvent ("onchange")

     Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_searchCDPList_ddlFieldName").selectedindex = 1
    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_searchCDPList_ddlFieldName").FireEvent ("onchange")
    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_searchCDPList_txtValue").Value = "Java"

    ' Click the "Search" button

    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_searchCDPList_btnSearch").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Your bold has been lost in the formatting. Please copy and paste the offending line of code into your question as an edit.

Comment: What line causes above error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4" loop doesn't really do what it's supposed to do. After getting the error, if you press Debug and then Continue the code, it will complete successfully. So, what is happening is that the element you're searching for still doesn't exist when the line first executes. You could patch this up with something like the following before the problem line:

```
Do While ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_searchCDPList_ddlFieldName") Is Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
```

This will loop until the element is found, then the code continues successfully.